# Regex working on regex101 and not on Splunk

Tags: regex, pcre, splunk

I would like to capture the word unknown and anything after abcd, abcd.com\ and unknown

```
unknown                     
abcd\svc-backup
abcd\swt034         
abcd\svc-app-login  
abcd.com\chi572 
abcd\daj144 
abcd\smi556
abcd\mki317
abcd\aiw014
abcd\joh488
abcd\ymc965 
abcd\jet041
abcd\rjo220 
abcd\mst790
abcd.com\sre590
```

It captures fine with the regex

https://regex101.com/r/c9vdia/2/

But when I use this in the Splunk search its just throwing my domain

```
index="paloalto"
| table user 
| rex field=user "(?P<user_name>((?:abcd\([A-Za-z0-9-]+|\w+)))"
```

I am only getting the domain name (abcd) but users without domain looks good.

Comment: What should happen to `firstname.lastname`?

Comment: Its extracting as well. Only abcd and acd.com has the issue

Comment: But you are not using the same regex, you are trying to match a `)` by escaping it. See https://regex101.com/r/v08cz7/2. Try `(?P<user_name>(?:abcd.*\\)([A-Za-z0-9-]+)|\w+.?)` Note that if you want to match the dot literally you have to escape it. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v08cz7/1)

Comment: To get a bit more precise match, you might try `(?P<user_name>(?:abcd[^\\]*\\)([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)|\w+\.?)` See https://regex101.com/r/oW65Fr/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its still its extracting it as abcd\ :( not the actual user name

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, based on your sample data:

```
(?<username>[a-z0-9A-Z\-\_\.\w]+)(\s?)+$
```

There are probably more efficient formulations. If you don't have spaces at the end of the line, you can use this:

```
(?<username>[a-z0-9A-Z\-\_\.]+)$
```